# 2x2 figure and caption alignment: clash with packages subcaption, subfigure and subfigures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subcaption, sidebyside

I am trying to align three figures and their three captions as the following 2x2 (four square) pattern: [image: what I want to do]

In order to solve this, I have the following code which works, but not in aesthetic appeal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{graphicx} 
%\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}

            \begin{subfigure}[]{0.50\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figure1.png}
                     \label{fig:networks}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                    \subcaption{An example of Network where $V_a=\ 
 {1,2,3,4\}, E_a=\{\{1,2\},V_b=\{5,6,7,8,9\},E_b=\{\{6,7\},\{8,9\}\}\},E_c=\ 
{\{1,5\},\{1,6\},\{2,6\},\{2,7\},\{3,5\},\{3,7\},\{4,5\},\{4,8\}\}$}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figure2.png}
                    \caption{ Type 1 sub network of the Network}
                    \label{fig:pattern1}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
                       \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figure3.png}
                       \caption{Type 2 sub network of the Network}
                       \label{fig:pattern2}
            \end{subfigure}
    \caption{An example of a Network with type 1 and type 2 sub networks}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the link to overleaf for this code: [The above code in overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/spgqhzggtjnx)

However, this falls apart when I uncomment `\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}`
I am collaborating on this with some other folks in a file that has subfigure package included with scriptsize, and I cannot remove that. I am trying to work my way around, but can't see how. Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: I don't have enough reputation to do it myself, but if a #2x2 could be created, it may help these type of questions

Comment: The `subfigure` package was marked obsolete by its author more than 15(!) years ago.

Answer (score 3):

package `subfigure` is obsolete and as i see you not use it in your document. it also clash with used `subcaption` package. so you should delete
`\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}` and set font size for for `subfigure`s environments for example with `\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{subcaption}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{subcaption}        % <---
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}     % <---
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{figure1.png}% <---
\caption{}
\label{fig:networks}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\raggedright                % <---
An example of Network where                         % <---
$\begin{aligned}                                    % <---
V_a & = \{1,2,3,4\},    \\
E_a & = \{\{1,2\},      \\
V_b & = \{5,6,7,8,9\},  \\
E_b & = \{\{6,7\},\{8,9\}\}\},  \\
E_c & = \begin{multlined}[t]\{\{1,5\},\{1,6\},\{2,6\},\\
        \{2,7\},\{3,5\},\{3,7\},\{4,5\},\{4,8\}\}
        \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}$
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,]{figure2.png}
\caption{ Type 1 sub network of the Network}
\label{fig:pattern1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth} % <---
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                 height=0.5\linewidth]{figure3.png} % <---
\caption{Type 2 sub network of the Network}
\label{fig:pattern2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{An example of a Network with type 1 and type 2 sub networks}
 \label{fig:networks}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]